# Cannot ask question because tag not working?

Tags: bug, tags, asking-questions

At this question just click tag blank or type something show option

But at Stack Overflow nothing appear, so I can't click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

What should I do?

> [image]

Comment: @Glorfindel There's no answer, just duplicate chain. I just remove chrome extend program. And It works.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the issue is with a Chrome Extension called OneTab which I had.

After removing it, everything works fine.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, others with same issue will save themselves time now. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, Try to switch to traditional editor. It worked for me.
How to switch to traditional editor:
Ignore, tag and title sections, when you are asked to input your question, there is a little button at right upper corner, click on it.